# Coupled differential equations method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = (x-y)y$$

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = -y$$

How can I solve for $x(t), y(t)$?
Is there a general method?

Comment: Differentiating the second equation with respect to $t$ allows elimination of $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}$ from the first equation.  Solving for $y$ in the secon equation eliminates $y$ from the first.  So you are left with a nonlinear second order ODE.  **A** general method for both of these is to compute their set of Lie symmetries and determine whether the resulting Lie group is solvable.  (This method will also tell you if there's a change of variables to constant coefficients or to other "helpful" forms.)

Comment: I do not think you wiil have a closed form solution.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The first thing you might do is put it on the machine and see what it looks   like. It seems that without initial conditions this is necessary, perhaps it's a well known system.

Comment: It's Grapher, a very easy to use Macintosh application that is in the utilities folder. I don't know why it isn't a bigger hit.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\displaystyle\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}} = y-x.$$
This is now a simple first order problem, with solutions $y = c\mathrm{e}^x+x+1.$ I think @Alan got his equations mixed around.

Comment: Yup, you're right, I took the equations in the wrong order .